# safari visibleContentsAsDataURL() is undefined

Tags: safari, safari-extension

My goal is to take screenshot of a webpage using safari 6 via an extension. I am using this in my extension global page:

```
function handle_message(event) {
         event.target.page.dispatchMessage("handle_message",
  {image:
   safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.visibleContentsAsDataURL()
  }
}

safari.application.addEventListener("message",handle_message,false);
```

On the receiving end the event message.image is undefined. Is there anything I need to do different. I can successfully send other tab properties such as url, just not the screenshot data image url. Any idea?

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself, the method needs a callback (of course)

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.visibleContentsAsDataURL(
  function(image_url){
       //do something with image_url
  }
)
```